# JBOSS service getting hanged on production server

Tags: multithreading, vaadin, jboss7.x, heap-dump

Can someone please give detailed way to find RCA for JBOSS app server ? The production application running on JBOSS server starts working fine after restarting the JBOSS service. How do I identify what is the cause behind it? we have completed below analysis but no RCA found, this JBOSS hung is happening twice in every month and millions of users using this application, outage causes lot of business loss

1. Thread dump analysis
2. heap dump analysis
3. CPU utilization
4. DB transactions
5. SQL queries during jboss hung
6. server log analysis
7. checked GC logs and memory leak in code

i need next approach which i can follow to find RCA